# data with function return vs. return plain data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I started with Vue.js I read about a case where you return a data property with **return** and sometimes without. I cannot find that article anymore that's why I'm asking here.

That's how I use it today

```
 data: function () {
      return {
        myData : "data"
      }
    },
```

But that's how I see it in documentation very often - don't know the difference anymore:

```
 data: {
    myData: "data"
  },
```

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing, but didn't bother to research it. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 3):

https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-does-data-need-to-be-a-function

> **Why does data need to be a function?**
>
> In the basic examples, we declare the `data` directly as a plain object. This is because we are creating only a single instance with `new Vue()`. However, when defining a **component**, `data` must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object. Why? Because there will be many instances created using the same definition. If we still use a plain object for `data`, that same object will be **shared by reference** across all instance created! By providing a `data` function, every time a new instance is created, we can simply call it to return a fresh copy of the initial data.